# Auto connect to BLE device in iOS app

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am writing an iOS application which will communicate to a device using Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE).

When my connected device  is out of range, my application is getting disconnect event.

But I am not getting any connect event when the device comes back to the range.

Please suggest any approach to detect when the device comes back to the range.

Comment: It would help if you could post a relevant example from your code. Are you attempting to reconnect to the peripheral?

Answer (score 1):

Just reconnect in your disconnect method if the connection times out. There's no need to start a scan. It will automatically try to reconnect until it gets in range.

Comment: This is correct. Connection attempts do not time out (as stated in the Apple documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBCentralManager_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CBCentralManager/connectPeripheral:options:).
Just be sure to also keep a reference to the peripheral object, otherwise the connection gets canceled.

Comment: However you might be out of luck if you need this to work for a long time of inactivity, if you are running in background mode. The system may crash your app and it won't restart it if bluetooth has been turned off and on, either if the user did it in the UI or bluetooth crashed and was restarted.

Answer (score 0):

when you get the event that the device is no reachable anymore, you can launch a method which continuously checks if the device is still not reachable.

For example: while(isConnected==false)...
You say that you get a notification if the device disconnects, so you can use that event to launch such a method

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply.

 I start the search in background thread, app may be rejected by apple. As background pooling is not allowed in iOS.

Answer (score 0):

When you receive the disconnect event, just restart the scan function:`scanForPeripheralsWithServices` or you can setup the scan mode to accept duplicate key by `[_manager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:self.targetDeviceServiceIDs options:@{CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey:@YES}]`. which means the same device would be discovered for many time until you stop scanning.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply.

But when i am getting disconnection event and if I start the scan in background, app may be rejected by apple. As background pooling is not allowed in iOS.

Comment: In that case you can retain the peripheral you connected, and setup a timer maybe every few seconds to try to reconnect it. It would trigger either 
`- centralManager:didConnectPeripheral:` or 
`- centralManager:didFailToConnectPeripheral:error:`

Answer (score 0):

When your device get disconnected or goto out of range of Bluetooth then you don't need to scan for Peripheral devices because it already scanned for the BLE devices.

Call function `[centralObj connectPeripheral:peripheral options:nil];` into `didDisconnectPeripheral` delegate method when BLE device disconnected.