# bluetooth auto pair if BT name is the same

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, ios-bluetooth, pairing

I would like to know if its possible to auto pair another bluetooth device with the same name.

I am trying to create a universal way of pairing and communicating with several devices.

For example, with BT headset, once paired, if turned off and on, it will auto pair back to the bluetooth device.

Is it possible, if other devices have the same name, can it be auto-paired ? If not, is there a way to auto-pair other bluetooth device ?

With WIFI is possible, if you create multiple WIFI with the same SSID and same password, its possible to move through different WIFI access points. I am trying to achieve something like that.

Comment: What kind of devices are we talking about? You do not need to pair devices when using BLE devices that do not use encryption.

Comment: They are just IOT devices around the home that I would like to connect when it is in close proximity. Can you provide some information on this how it can auto-connect ? I was told there is BLE low energy instead of the traditional bluetooth, but still not clear how it would achieve this.

Comment: When using BLE you need an app that communicates with the device. That is because every device might use a different service or even custom ones. So if you are writing an app that scans for the devices around you you could start filling a list of known devices and connect to them once they come in range. For iOS you can find some ideas here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37347488/auto-connect-to-ble-device-in-ios-app